# Android Location Permission Check in Java Code

Tags: android, permissions, gps, location, maps

I am attempting to use android location services on a google MapsActivity on API 23. I have the permissions in the manifest file as such:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

When I attempt to use:

```
mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
```

It shows an error that generates a permission checking code (below). And I do not know what to enter in the block; is seems that the conditional statement is already doing the necessary checks.

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return;
        }
```

It seems like anything I enter in this conditional results in and error.

Comment: Take a look at the code in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34774869/4409409

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(App.getContext(),
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) { // Marshmallow

                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
                }

            } else { // no need to ask for permission

                // start to find location...
            }
```

And add this:

```
@Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

        if (requestCode == LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE) {

            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // start to find location...

            } else { // if permission is not granted

                // decide what you want to do if you don't get permissions
            }
        }
    }
```

`LOCATION_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE` is a `final int` you set in your class (1252 for example).

Also read [this](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/best-practices.html), for permissions best practices.